# Issue creating reflected getter for private field

Tags: c#, getter, cil

Working with Rider IDE 2019.1.3 and DotNetCore 2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I have the following piece of code:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dictionary.Add(1,2);

FieldInfo field = dictionary.GetType().GetField("_keys", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);


string methodName = string.Concat(field.ReflectedType.FullName, ".get_", field.Name);
DynamicMethod getterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, field.FieldType, new [] { typeof(Dictionary<int, int>) }, true);
ILGenerator gen = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
if (field.IsStatic)
{
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, field);
}
else
{
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
}
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var getter = (Func<Dictionary<int, int>, Dictionary<int, int>.KeyCollection>)getterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Dictionary<int, int>, Dictionary<int, int>.KeyCollection>));

var result = (object)getter(dictionary);
```

When I execute this code normally the `result` would be `null` but if I set a breakpoint before and access the dictionary in the debugger session and actually have a look at this internal collection (by expanding the object tree) I see the content. If I then continue to execute the code the correct value can be retrieved and `result` is not `null`.

Why does it only work if I look at this field with the debugger? How can I get it to work properly?

I tried various things and if I not wrong it does not relate to the fact that this field is generic for example. I was not able to write a class myself where the behavior is similar.

Note: For a project that analyzes the state of instances I am interesting in reading private fields in general. This dictionary is just an example I came across where this approach does not work.

Comment: Use a compiled expression tree instead, like this example: https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/02/26/linq-expressions-access-private-fields/

Comment: Thanks but I would also like to know how to do it with the ILGenerator and know what is causing the effect that I see.

Comment: You probably will have to use your native debugger to look at the machine code which the JIT produced, and do it both with and without the managed debugger attached, because this affects the JIT optimization level.

Comment: My experience with ILGenerator usage in Reflection.Emit has been maddening due to lack of documentation, however it would just fail to run the resulting DLL if I did the wrong thing, I never got unpredictable behavior.  Never had any luck with DynamicMethod, though.

Comment: I can reproduce this using visual studio 2019 preview with dotnet core 3.0 on windows. Using the debugger itself does not seem to trigger the behavior, i have to expand the object tree until i see the _keys field to get the result (as OP described).

Comment: You might try using ILSpy to inspect the generated IL and decompiled C#.  If it's not precisely what you expect, it might provide a clue on what needs to be changed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see the same behavior with compiled expression trees btw.

Comment: There is no issue. Your code is working perfectly. The problem is that the `_keys` field is populated by reading the `Keys` property, which you haven't done.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, this is the answer it seems! Thanks a lot.